# Populate Dates and Days in Javascript : Input : Month and Year

Tags: javascript, date

I wish to get all the dates in a month and year.

Example : **Input** : **January, 2014**

**Output**: 1,2,3,.. endOfMonth(31) along with Days (Sunday, Monday... )

Comment: Can you post some code of your attempt at solving this problem?

Comment: Thanks dude. I Got the solutions... 1. Found the no.of days in the selected month and year. 2. Then Iterated till the noOfDays.

Answer (score 0):

1. Found the no.of days in the selected month and year.
2. Then Iterated till the noOfDays.